# .Net Core JSON response is getting truncated

Tags: c#, json, docker, .net-core

In .Net Core, a large JSON response is getting truncated in the view and there is no exception raised while deserializing it. This happens when there is a heavy network traffic and the issue gets resolved for some time after restarting the app on docker.

```
ViewBag.JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstViewCategory.OrderBy(x => x.CollectionName));
```

Comment: What do you mean by getting truncated in `View`?

Comment: set maxAllowedContentLength in web.config?

Comment: We have set those properties and it is not happening everytime, this is a random issue. And after killing some threads on server it starts working

Comment: after disabling proxy buffering issue got resolved to certain extent but now once in 2-3 request response gets truncate